# Understanding Ruby Classes and Modules

Tags: ruby, oop, class, syntax, mixins

I have a number of questions regarding ruby classes and modules. I have written a number of test files to kind of explore them further that are too long to post here (https://github.com/Senjai/Learning-Ruby/blob/master/class_test.rb and https://github.com/Senjai/Learning-Ruby/blob/master/mixin-instance-var-conflict.rb)

First three questions are about variables.

So far that I understand it, instance variables are prefixed with @, and are unique to each instance of the class. They can only be accessed with accessor methods (like attr_accessor)

Second, class variables, they're prefixed by @@. 
**How come class variables can't be used with attr_accessor/reader?**
What's the difference between class.class_variable and instance.class_variable? If an instance modifies a class variable from within the class (e.g in an instance method) does that affect the static variable in the class definition?

Thirdly,

Why do instance/class variables need to be prefixed with @? What happens when they aren't prefixed at all? Like in the example below:

```
module Test
  State = {}
  def state=(value)
    State[object_id] = value
  end
  def state
    State[object_id]
  end
end
```

For class methods, I understand that instance methods are defined as normal functions, and class methods have to be prefixed with self. Why can't you use class methods in an instantiated object? Why does self make it so special?

Lastly, for the scope resolution operator, I've only found that it works for constants and class methods, what's the point of having a scope resolution operator in the first place if they can be accessed in dot notation?

Comment: This would be so much more manageable if it were indeed three separate questions.  But I will state that `State` is not an instance variable without @ or @@.  It is a constant.  So doesn't apply to your question.  If it were lowercase `state` it would simply be a local variable.

Comment: Split this into separate questions.